If sum of $a^2 +b^2 +x^2 +y^2$ is constant, find the maximum output value of $(ax -by)^2 + (bx+ay)^2$
I transformed polynomial into $(x^2 + y^2)(a^2 + b^2)$.
First thing first, I don't understand what it means that the expression above is constant.
Does it mean that it always has the same output value k,no matter which values have input variables.For example, can it be that the expression is always equal 5.
The solution is $(a^2 +b^2)^2$,obviously $x^2 + y^2=a^2 + b^2$.But I don't understand why for that value function output is the maximum possible.

Sum of $a^2 +b^2 +x^2 +y^2$ constant means that the sum of the squares of these variables is always the same.

So, you appear to be saying is: given a constant $C,$ find the maximum value of (second expression) given $a^2+b^2+x^2+y^2=C.$

If $a^2 + b^2 + x^2 + y^2= 5$ why do think the maximum value of $(x^2+y^2)(a^2 + b^2)$ is "obviously" when $x^2+y^2=a^2+b^2$ and what do you actually think that value actually is?

If $a=x=0$ and $b=y=\sqrt{\frac 52}$ we get $(a^2+b^2)^2=\frac{25}4$ but if $a=x=1$ and $b=y=\sqrt{2}$ we get $(a^2+b^2)^2=9$ so saying the max is obviously $(a^2 + b^2)^2$ when $x^2+y^2=a^2 +b^2$ is not an answer.

Let $C\geq0$ be the constant.
If you set $u=a^2+b^2, v=x^2+y^2,$ you've already reduced it to maximizing $uv$ given $u+v=C$
But by $AM/GM,$ $$\frac{C}2=\frac{u+v}{2}\geq \sqrt{uv}$$
or $uv\leq\frac{C^2}4.$ You only get equality when $u=v=\frac C2,$ then you can let $a=b=x=y=\frac{\sqrt{C}}{2}$ to prove we can achieve this value $C^2/4.$

Thank you ,you explained key concept I didn't know which is basically this:https://imgur.com/a/VNQFp3p

$a^2+b^2+x^2+y^2$ being constant means that we can take all values of $a,b,x,y$ such that this expression is always the same value. Maybe, $a$ and $b$ are parameters here, and we can only change $x$ and $y$. In this case answer in terms of $a$ and $b$ is relevant.
$$\begin{align}(ax -by)^2 + (bx+ay)^2&=(ax)^2+(by)^2-2abxy+(bx)^2+(ay)^2+2abxy\\
&= (ax)^2+(by)^2+(bx)^2+(ay)^2\\
&=(a^2+b^2)(x^2+y^2)\end{align}$$
If sum of two numbers ($a^2+b^2$ and $x^2+y^2$) is constant, then its product is maximal, when they are equal. Hence maximum is $(a^2+b^2)^2$ indeed.

Yeah thats the solution in the book,however I don't understand why is the case what you are saying:"If sum of two numbers
is constant, then its product is maximal, when they are equal. "

@StephanieV Let two numbers $u$ and $v$ have a constant sum. Let us denote their arithmetic mean as $s$. Then $u=s-d$, $v=s+d$ for some $d$. Hence $uv=(s-d)(s+d)=s^2-d^2\le s^2$. The maximum is $s^2$ and is obtained when $d=0$, which means $u=v=s$.

The constraint that $a^2+b^2+x^2+y^2$ is constant means there exists a constant $\xi$ such that $$a^2+b^2+x^2+y^2=\xi.$$ Note that such a $\xi$ must be non-negative.
Define $A=a^2$, $B=b^2$, $X=x^2$, and $Y=y^2$. Let $\theta = A+B$ and note that $X+Y=\xi-\theta$, since we have the constraint $$a^2+b^2+x^2+y^2=\xi.$$
No constraints on $a,b,x,y$ translate into the constraints that $A,B,X,Y\geqslant 0$.
Note that \begin{align*}(ax-by)^2+(bx+ay)^2 & = AX-2abxy+BY \\ & + BX+2abxy+AY \\ & = (A+B)(X+Y)=\theta(\xi-\theta). \end{align*}
Using single variable optimization to get that the value is maximized when $$\theta=\xi-\theta=\frac{\xi}{2}=\frac{A+B+X+Y}{2}.$$   But $\theta=\xi-\theta$ means $A+B=X+Y$, so $$\theta=\xi-\theta=\frac{A+B+X+Y}{2}=\frac{A+B+A+B}{2}=A+B=X+Y.$$  Therefore the maximum is $$\theta(\xi-\theta)=(A+B)^2.$$

Let
$$R^2 = a^2+b^2+x^2+y^2$$
and consider
$$f(a,b,x,y) = (ax-by)^2+(bx+ay)^2$$
$$= \left(a^2+b^2\right)\left(x^2+y^2\right)$$
$$= \left(a^2+b^2\right)\left(R^2-(a^2+b^2)\right)$$
Parameterize $a$ and $b$ using polar coordinates $\rho$ and $\theta$ such that $a=\rho \cos(\theta)$ and $b=\rho \sin(\theta)$. Then our expression becomes.
$$f(a,b,x,y) = \left(a^2+b^2\right)\left(R^2-(a^2+b^2)\right)$$
$$= \rho^2\left(R^2-\rho^2\right) \equiv f(\rho^2)$$
This is a quadratic function in the variable $\rho^2$ so its maximum occurs at the vertex $\rho^2=R^2/2$.
$$f\left(\rho^2=R^2/2\right)= \frac{R^2}{2}\left(R^2-\frac{R^2}{2}\right)$$
$$= \frac{R^4}{4}$$
$$= \boxed{\frac{\left(a^2+b^2+x^2+y^2\right)^2}{4}}$$
